# Discrete and Dynamic system Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, discrete-mathematics

I'm using recusive least squares (RLS) to identify system parameters for a dynamical system. The RLS algorithm is implemented in discrete time, while the real system is continuous. In practice this is easily done, but how can I simulate these two together? A sequential solution doesn't help, since I want to use the RLS estimate to influence the system input.

The built-in event-triggering can only stop integration, if I got that right. Thus, I'd have to stop at each sampling point of the RLS algorithm and then solve the ode between samples. -> How is this implemented in Simulink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real solution I found was to implement my own RK45 with adaptive step size. It is designed to take discrete and continuous systems (ode and difference equations) and solves with adaptive step size until a new sample has to be taken. This method works like a charm - with slow dynamics only the discrete points are sampled for sufficiently small sampling times and fast dynamics yield small integration step sizes, as expected!

Also the implementation was way less effort than expected and compares surprisingly well to matlabs ode45, ie. lower computational cost, higher accuracy, less oscillations after discrete jumps in the ode!